# If i use index inside my map the Reactjs SPFx web part will not return anything.. any advice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get the current Index inside a `.map` inside a React SPFx web part, as follow:-

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';
    
    import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
    import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';
    
    export interface INews {
        recentNews: ISingleNewsProps[];
        featuredNews?: ISingleNewsProps[];
        featured: boolean;
    }
    
    export default class SingleNews extends React.Component<INews, {}> {
        public render(): React.ReactElement<INews> {
            return (
                <>
                <table>
                    {this.props.featured
                        ? this.props.recentNews.map((post,index) =>{ 
    if(index===0)
{
    
        <tr><td>
                            <a
                                className={styles.singleNews}
                                href={post.link}
                                key={post.Title}
                            >
                                <div
                                    className={styles.singleNews__image}
                                    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
                                />
                                <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                                    <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                                        <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                                        <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                                            {post.date}
                                        </span></div>
                                </div>
                                <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                                    <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
    
                                        <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                                            {post.Title}
                                        </h2>
    
    
    
                                        {post.likes ? (
                                            <div
                                                className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                                            >
                                                <span
                                                    className={
                                                        styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                                                    }
                                                >
                                                    <Icon iconName='Like' />
                                                    {post.likes}
                                                </span>
                                                <span>
                                                    <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                                                    {post.coments}
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        ) : null}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a></td></tr>}
                        })
                          }</table>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```

but the above will not return any thing.. now if i remove the index i will get the table:-

```
   export default class SingleNews extends React.Component<INews, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INews> {
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.featured
                    ? this.props.recentNews.map(post => (
```

so can anyone advice? on this?
Thanks

**Here is my edit, but i got errors syntax errors :-**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';

import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';

export interface INews {
    recentNews: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featuredNews?: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featured: boolean;
}

export default class SingleNews extends React.Component<INews, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INews> {
        return (
            <><table>
                {this.props.featured
                    ? this.props.recentNews.map((post,index) => {
{index === 0 ? 
<tr>
<td rowSpan={2}>
<a
    className={styles.singleNews}
    href={post.link}
    key={post.Title}
>
    <div
        className={styles.singleNews__image}
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
    />
    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                {post.date}
            </span></div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>

            <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                {post.Title}
            </h2>



            {post.likes ? (
                <div
                    className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                >
                    <span
                        className={
                            styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                        }
                    >
                        <Icon iconName='Like' />
                        {post.likes}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                        {post.coments}
                    </span>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    </div>
</a></td> : null }

{index === 1 ? 

    <td >
    <a
        className={styles.singleNews}
        href={post.link}
        key={post.Title}
    >
        <div
            className={styles.singleNews__image}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
        />
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                    {post.date}
                </span></div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
    
                <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                    {post.Title}
                </h2>
    
    
    
                {post.likes ? (
                    <div
                        className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                    >
                        <span
                            className={
                                styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                            }
                        >
                            <Icon iconName='Like' />
                            {post.likes}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                            {post.coments}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a></td></tr> : null }
    {index === 2 ? 
        <tr>
        <td >
        <a
            className={styles.singleNews}
            href={post.link}
            key={post.Title}
        >
            <div
                className={styles.singleNews__image}
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
            />
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                    <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                    <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                        {post.date}
                    </span></div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
        
                    <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                        {post.Title}
                    </h2>
        
        
        
                    {post.likes ? (
                        <div
                            className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                        >
                            <span
                                className={
                                    styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                                }
                            >
                                <Icon iconName='Like' />
                                {post.likes}
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                                {post.coments}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </a></td></tr> : null }                 
                    })
                    
                                : null
                      }
            </table></>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(index=0)` is assignment. Do you mean `if(index===0)`?

Comment: @Nick ok change it to `if(index===0)` but still the same issue

Comment: you need `return` after `if`

Comment: @evgenifotia what do you mean? can you explain in more details please?

Comment: @evgenifotia i already have a return ...

Comment: this is what you have `if(index===0) { <tr><td>` this is what you should do `if(index===0) { return <tr key={your key}><td>`

Comment: @evgenifotia but the idea i need to dynamically render HTML based on the index.. so the return should proceed the If

Comment: `if(index === 0) { return ....} else if(index === 1} { return ...... }` if you doesn't return inside the `if` statement then nothing will get rendered when the `if` conditionne is meet

Comment: @evgenifotia but  i need to return a table, but dynamically build the rows,, as shown in my code

Comment: @evgeni fotia
 can you check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you could just do it with jsx inside your return. No need for a IF statement.

So first off you are missing the return completely in the top statement which is why it returns nothing.

```
...? this.props.recentNews.map((post,index) => {
    return(
    {index === 0 ? undefined : <> //YOUR HTML CODE HERE </> }
    )
}
```

This will render everything in your array except the first value(s)

EDIT 2 -- you still have not included the return like I have above.

Copy and paste the code snippet below and it should work now. If you get any syntax errors please post the error.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import * as React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';

import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';

export interface INews {
    recentNews: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featuredNews?: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featured: boolean;
}

export default class SingleNews extends React.Component<INews, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INews> {
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.featured
                    ? this.props.recentNews.map((post,index) => {
                    return(
                    <>
                    <table>
{index === 0 ? 
<tr>
<td rowSpan={2}>
<a
    className={styles.singleNews}
    href={post.link}
    key={post.Title}
>
    <div
        className={styles.singleNews__image}
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
    />
    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                {post.date}
            </span></div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>

            <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                {post.Title}
            </h2>



            {post.likes ? (
                <div
                    className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                >
                    <span
                        className={
                            styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                        }
                    >
                        <Icon iconName='Like' />
                        {post.likes}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                        {post.coments}
                    </span>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    </div>
</a></td> : index === 1 ? 
    <td >
    <a
        className={styles.singleNews}
        href={post.link}
        key={post.Title}
    >
        <div
            className={styles.singleNews__image}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
        />
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                    {post.date}
                </span></div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
    
                <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                    {post.Title}
                </h2>
    
    
    
                {post.likes ? (
                    <div
                        className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                    >
                        <span
                            className={
                                styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                            }
                        >
                            <Icon iconName='Like' />
                            {post.likes}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                            {post.coments}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a></td></tr> : null }
    {index === 2 ? 
        <tr>
        <td >
        <a
            className={styles.singleNews}
            href={post.link}
            key={post.Title}
        >
            <div
                className={styles.singleNews__image}
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
            />
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                    <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                    <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                        {post.date}
                    </span></div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
        
                    <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                        {post.Title}
                    </h2>
        
        
        
                    {post.likes ? (
                        <div
                            className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                        >
                            <span
                                className={
                                    styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                                }
                            >
                                <Icon iconName='Like' />
                                {post.likes}
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                                {post.coments}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </a></td></tr> : null }   
        </table>
        </>
        )})}
       </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: as you can see i need to return a table, but dynamically build the rows

Comment: Updated my answer so logic will work inside

Comment: can you check my edit please

Comment: @johnGu Please check the updated answer and reply